# Adding new keyframe messes up object location in a timeline

Tags: animation

I am working on an animation. When I try to add a rotation to my object it for some reasons changes other normals and animation looks like a mess.

Set up
[image]

Adding rotation
[image]

Applying it
[image]

And after I applied it changes all location data
[image]

Comment: Since you're using Location and Rotation for your anim, set a keyframe for these two. On the screenshot you provide where you insert the keyframe, select "Location and Rotation* instead of only the rotation

Comment: I have no idea what exactly is going on there, but even the "not messed up" keyframes before inserting a new one show completely different values than what is visible in the _Location_ and _Rotation_ fields in the viewport... was the bottle parented before or something like that? The new values at the keyframe after inserting seem to match the ones in the viewport as far as I can tell from the screenshot.

Comment: @B.Pader Since there already is a keyframe on the location (it's shown in yellow), there's absolutely no need to do this unless he changed the location. In fact, since the rotation seems to be messed up somehow because the values are not matching, he might even mess up the location as well.

Comment: @Vlad: as you can see in the comments...people are guessing around. So pls provide blend file since you didn't provide necessary informations to solve this issue. thx. Also your are using here different terms like "applying": applying a rotation is something totally different to adding a keyframe to rotation - i hope you know that. Because for your pictures you write "applying" but you show us, how you insert keyframes - so tbh your pictures do not fit to what you have written.